# Trying to program ESP32 with manual switch feedback

Tags: python, esp32, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

i want to make a program where i can manage appliances using MQTT messages as well as i want to take feedback using normal switches, i tried the following code but in that case switch one and relay on is operating as expected but switch2 & switch 3 are getting called in loop and switch 2 is automatically getting converted from 0 to 1 and hence if condition is getting verified and its getting in loop, please help

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include "ArduinoJson.h"


#define relayOne 15
#define switchOne 32
#define relayTwo 2
#define switchTwo 35
#define relayThree 4
#define switchThree 34
#define relayFour 22
#define switchFour 39

const char* ssid = "*******";//replace this with your wifi access point 
const char * password = ""*******";//"; //replace with your wifi password
const char * host = "*.*.*.*"; //IP address of machine on which broker is installed
const int port = 1883;
const char * mqttUser = "user";
const char * mqttPassword = "user";

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

StaticJsonBuffer < 55 > jsonBuffer;

void callback(char * topic, byte * payload, unsigned int length) {

  Serial.print("Message received in topic: ");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("   length is:");
  Serial.println(length);
  Serial.print("Data Received From Broker:");

  String messageTemp;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    messageTemp += (char) payload[i];
  }
  //Serial.println(messageTemp);
  const size_t capacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(2) + 20;
  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(capacity);

  //const char* json = "{\"pin\":14,\"value\":1}";
  const char * json = messageTemp.c_str();

  JsonObject & root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);

  int pin = root["pin"];
  int value = root["value"];

  Serial.println(pin);
  Serial.println(value);
  digitalWrite(pin, value);

}




void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  pinMode(relayOne, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(switchOne, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(relayTwo, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(switchTwo, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(relayThree, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(switchThree, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(relayFour, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(switchFour, INPUT_PULLUP);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(100);
    yield();
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");

  client.setServer(host, port);
  client.setCallback(callback);

  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT...");

    if (client.connect("ESP8266Client", mqttUser, mqttPassword)) {
      Serial.println("connected to MQTT broker");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed with state ");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      delay(500);
    }
  }

  Serial.println("ESP32 AS SUBSCRIBER");
  client.subscribe("IOT"); //topic name="Sub"
}

void MQTTPOST(int pin, int value)
{
  Serial.println("in mqttpost");
  //payload formation begins here
  String payload ="{";
  payload +="\"Pin\":"; payload +=pin; payload +=",";
  payload +="\"Value\":"; payload +=value;
  payload +="}";
  
  char attributes[1000];
  payload.toCharArray( attributes, 1000 );
  client.publish("IOT1", attributes); //topic="Pub" MQTT data post command.
  Serial.println( attributes );
  Serial.println("");
}


int switchOneValue = 0;
int switchTwoValue = 0;
int switchThreeValue = 0;
int switchFourValue = 0;
void loop() {
  client.loop();

  int valueSwitchOne = digitalRead(switchOne);
  Serial.println(valueSwitchOne);
   Serial.println(switchOneValue);
   if(valueSwitchOne == 0 && switchOneValue == 0){
    digitalWrite(relayOne, 1);
    switchOneValue = 1;
    MQTTPOST(relayOne, 1);
    Serial.println("on");
    delay(200);
   }else if(valueSwitchOne == 1 && switchOneValue == 1) {
    digitalWrite(relayOne, 0);
    switchOneValue = 0;
    MQTTPOST(relayOne, 0);
    Serial.println("off");
    delay(200);
   }

  int valueSwitchTwo = digitalRead(switchTwo);
  Serial.println(valueSwitchTwo);
   Serial.println(switchTwoValue);
   delay(1000);
   if(valueSwitchTwo == 0 && switchTwoValue == 0){
    digitalWrite(relayTwo, 1);
    switchTwoValue = 1;
    MQTTPOST(relayTwo, 1);
    Serial.println("on2");
    delay(200);
   }else if(valueSwitchTwo == 1 && switchTwoValue == 1) {
    digitalWrite(relayTwo, 0);
    switchTwoValue = 0;
    MQTTPOST(relayTwo, 0);
    Serial.println("off2");
    delay(200);
   }

     int valueSwitchThree = digitalRead(switchThree);
   if(valueSwitchThree == 0 && switchThreeValue == 0){
    digitalWrite(relayThree, 1);
    switchThreeValue = 1;
    MQTTPOST(relayThree, 1);
    Serial.println("on");
    delay(200);
   }else if(valueSwitchThree == 1 && switchThreeValue == 1) {
    digitalWrite(relayThree, 0);
    switchThreeValue = 0;
    MQTTPOST(relayThree, 0);
    Serial.println("off");
    delay(200);
   }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of code there, which is fine, but given that the code doesn't work the way you want it to and we don't know what your desired goal for it is, it would help if you would tell us *exactly* what you want to see happen for the various switch combinations. It would also help if the code were indented and formatted consistently. There are tools - some are on the web - for formatting code that can help with this.

Also please don't tag this "arduino-esp8266" when it has nothing to do with the esp8266.

Comment: @romkey actually i am trying to make a program that works with manual switch as well with feedback and i have successfully done it with one relay, but when i try to add second relay the code gets to turn on and off automatically, so basically i want to control relay using MQTT as well as manual switch that too with feedback

Answer (score 0):

here is a quote from documentation on esp32:

> Appendix A – ESP32 Pin Lists
>
> A.1. Notes on ESP32 Pin Lists
>
> Table 24: Notes on ESP32 Pin Lists
>
> **GPIO pins 34-39** are input-only. These pins do **NOT** feature an output
> driver or **internal pull-up/pull-down** circuitry.

digitalRead() can return arbitrary value for those pins because there are no built-in pull-up resistors there - they are effectively dangling in the air.

It means that following code **CAN NOT WORK** without external pull-up resistors:

```cpp
#define switchTwo 35
#define switchThree 34
#define switchFour 39

pinMode(switchTwo, INPUT_PULLUP); // THIS DOES NOT WORK for GPIOs: 34-39!!!
pinMode(switchThree, INPUT_PULLUP); // THIS DOES NOT WORK for GPIOs: 34-39 !!!
pinMode(switchFour, INPUT_PULLUP); // THIS DOES NOT WORK for GPIOs: 34-39 !!!

// unpredictable values are here when button is not pressed
int valueSwitchTwo = digitalRead(35);
int valueSwitchThree = digitalRead(34);
```

**Solution:**

1. either use different pins for the switches
2. or add real hardware resistors into your schematics